# cubic bezier cuve different in ios and javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, bezier

Background:

In my application I have to draw a curve along the points where user taps the screen. I found below blog that explains how to calculate control points based on path points for bezier curves.

[Spline Interpolation - Scaled Innovation](http://scaledinnovation.com/analytics/splines/aboutSplines.html)

The example was in javascript and I adapted it to iOS. Below is the code I am using in my app

```
void (^calculateAndAddControlPoints)(CGPoint firstPoint, CGPoint secondPoint, CGPoint thirdPoint) = ^void (CGPoint firstPoint, CGPoint secondPoint, CGPoint thirdPoint)
{
    CGPoint controlPoint1;
    CGPoint controlPoint2;

    CGFloat distance12 = sqrt(pow(firstPoint.x-secondPoint.x, 2) + pow(firstPoint.y-secondPoint.y, 2));
    CGFloat distance23 = sqrt(pow(secondPoint.x-thirdPoint.x, 2) + pow(secondPoint.y-thirdPoint.y, 2));
    CGFloat scallingFactor12 = (tension * distance12) / (distance12 + distance23);
    CGFloat scallingFactor23 = tension - scallingFactor12;

    controlPoint1.x = secondPoint.x - (scallingFactor12 * (thirdPoint.x - firstPoint.x));
    controlPoint1.y = secondPoint.y - (scallingFactor12 * (thirdPoint.y - firstPoint.y));
    controlPoint2.x = secondPoint.x + (scallingFactor23 * (thirdPoint.x - firstPoint.x));
    controlPoint2.y = secondPoint.y + (scallingFactor23 * (thirdPoint.y - firstPoint.y));

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor);
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:controlPoint1];
    [path addLineToPoint:controlPoint2];
    [path stroke];

    [controlPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:controlPoint1]];
    [controlPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:controlPoint2]];
};
NSUInteger curvePointsCount = [curvePoints count];
if (_closed) {
    NSValue *lastPoint = [curvePoints lastObject];
    [curvePoints addObject:curvePoints[0]];
    [curvePoints addObject:curvePoints[1]];
    [curvePoints insertObject:lastPoint atIndex:0];
    for (NSInteger i=0; i < curvePointsCount; ++i) {
        calculateAndAddControlPoints([curvePoints[i + 0] CGPointValue],
                                     [curvePoints[i + 1] CGPointValue],
                                     [curvePoints[i + 2] CGPointValue]);
    }
    [controlPoints addObject:controlPoints[0]];
    [controlPoints addObject:controlPoints[1]];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:[curvePoints[1] CGPointValue]];
    for (NSInteger i=1; i < curvePointsCount + 1; ++i) {
        [path addCurveToPoint:[curvePoints[i + 1] CGPointValue]
                controlPoint1:[controlPoints[2 * i + 0] CGPointValue]
                controlPoint2:[controlPoints[2 * i + 1] CGPointValue]];
    }
    [path stroke];
} else {
    for (NSInteger i=0; i < curvePointsCount - 2; ++i) {
        calculateAndAddControlPoints([curvePoints[i + 0] CGPointValue],
                                     [curvePoints[i + 1] CGPointValue],
                                     [curvePoints[i + 2] CGPointValue]);
    }

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:[curvePoints[0] CGPointValue]];
    [path addQuadCurveToPoint:[curvePoints[1] CGPointValue]
                 controlPoint:[controlPoints[0] CGPointValue]];

    for (NSInteger i=1; i < curvePointsCount - 2; ++i) {
        [path addCurveToPoint:[curvePoints[i + 1] CGPointValue]
                controlPoint1:[controlPoints[2 * i + 0] CGPointValue]
                controlPoint2:[controlPoints[2 * i + 1] CGPointValue]];
    }

    [path moveToPoint:[curvePoints[curvePointsCount - 2] CGPointValue]];
    [path addQuadCurveToPoint:[curvePoints[curvePointsCount - 1] CGPointValue]
                 controlPoint:[controlPoints[[controlPoints count] - 1] CGPointValue]];
    [path stroke];
}
```

Problem:

The output in iOS is different from the output in javascript, as you can see below the curves are not smooth near the path points. The white lines are actual curve lines, the yellow lines are lines joining the control points and red dots are the curve points.

[image: iOS output]

This is how the same curve looks in javascript.

[image: javascript output]

The curve points used: (100, 100), (300, 100), (300, 300), (100, 300)

The control points generated: (50, 150), (150, 50), (250, 50), (350, 150), (350, 250), (250, 350), (150, 350), (50, 250)

Why didn't I get a circle in iOS, how to fix this?

Solution:

It turns out I was calculating control points properly but mapping them wrongly to curve points. Thanks to @gabbler I fixed it now, below is the proper loop for drawing the curve

```
for (NSInteger i=1; i < curvePointsCount + 1; ++i) {
    [_bezierPath moveToPoint:[curvePoints[i] CGPointValue]];
    [_bezierPath addCurveToPoint:[curvePoints[i + 1] CGPointValue]
            controlPoint1:[controlPoints[2 * i - 1] CGPointValue]
            controlPoint2:[controlPoints[2 * i + 0] CGPointValue]];
}
```

Comment: iOS shows you that the Catmull-Rom curve you've defined is entering and departing the curve points from the wrong direction. The tangents look right, so you seem to have lost some minus signs while you were porting to ensure the (dx,dy) stays (dx,dy) instead of becoming (-dx,-dy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a curve from (100,100) to (300,100), the control points should be (150,50) and (250,50), in your code, control points are instead (350,150) and (250,50), specifying the right control points should make it work.